# Apache Nifi 2.x- org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI

Tags: linux, centos, apache-nifi, elk

Hello i just installed APACHE Nifi and for testing purposes i have this configuration in nifi.properties
`<pre>nifi.web.https.host=127.0.0.1 nifi.web.https.port=8443 </pre>`
I saw a solution from here saying that Jetty 10 doesn't accept IP address but instead hostnames, so what I did was to change etc/hosts to 127.0.0.1 -> nifi.local and used that nifi.web.https.host=nifi.local for the configuration of the nifi. I run in browser https://nifi.local:8443 and i get the same error:( Can someone assist please?

`**HTTP ERROR 400 Invalid SNI
URI:    /nifi
STATUS: 400
MESSAGE:    Invalid SNI
SERVLET:    -
CAUSED BY:  org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI**
Caused by:

org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer.customize(SecureRequestCustomizer.java:266)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer.customize(SecureRequestCustomizer.java:207)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1594)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:461)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

`

Comment: So i edited /etc/hosts to set my ip adress as 'my.nifi'. I updated nifi.properties to my.nifi in web:https:host and when i restart nifi i get same error. Logs i get message "023-12-07 13:09:05,846 WARN [NiFi Web Server-36] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel handleException /nifi org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
2023-12-07 13:09:06,021 WARN [NiFi Web Server-33] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel handleException /favicon.ico org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.